# Ubuntu is not booting to GUI apt-get: /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

All of a sudden today my ubuntu system is not booting to GUI, I guess some system problem occured.

When I do:

> sudo apt-get upgrade

from a console, I get the following error:

> apt-get: /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` not found (required by apt-get)
>
> apt-get: /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12)

Can anyone help?
I don't wish to reflash my system.
Its running on 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

You have a local version of your libstdc++, which conflicts with the newer libstdc++-version, which your newer apt-get wants.

I don't know, where is your libstdc++ in your /usr/local/lib is coming from, but it is surely not from your ubuntu distribution. If you don't know that, probably you can delete that.

If you won't do that, a simple hotfix were for this if you renamed /usr/local/lib to f.e. /usr/local/lib- for the running of the apt-get command.

Comment: If I delete the libstdc++ from my system , will upgrade work?  Not sure how this lib would affect my system

Comment: @user2882240 You should delete the libstdc++ in your /usr/local/lib. It is a non-standard parallel libstdc++ installation, which conflicts with the system-standard installation in /usr/lib . And you don't need to delete the version in /usr/local/lib (if something is using it, it will break) it is enough if you make this temporarily unreachable by renaming the /usr/local/lib directory.